# Ansible retry loop untill the content of file is updated

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a ansible script where I am trying to fetch the time of the host. I have got the time of each host saved in the local file. Now, I am trying to reboot the host and save the new time of each host until the the timing value has actually changes until then I want to keep on retrying. Can anybody suggest how to work with that?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you just want to wait until the host rebooted?

Comment: I want to wait till the host is rebooted and then update the time of the host into an existing file

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```yaml
- name: reboot the host
  reboot:

- name: save time
  shell: 'date > /path/to/your/file'
```

The first task will reboot the host and block until all hosts are rebooted.
The second task will write the current time of the host into a file.

Comment: Maybe you should add delegate_to: localhost ? I think he wanted on a local file (Dont know if that's the case)